# How to calculate cut-off frequency of an RC High Pass filter with two resistors?

Tags: filter, remote-control

Please consider the attached circuit. How would I calculate the cut-off frequency here? Should I  treat resistors as attached in parallel? This is an actual circuit of an existing device, I cannot modify it. The signal is fed to a microcontroller.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How would I calculate the cut-off frequency here? Should I treat resistors as attached in parallel?

Yes.

You should assume that the +5 V is an AC ground, that is, has sufficient number of decoupling capacitors to ground and/or is driven from a low impedance regulator, so that signal currents flowing in and out of it don't change its voltage significantly.

You would then calculate the time constant as 100n * 5k.